# Cannot save match preferences on job search preferences

Tags: bug, status-norepro, developer-story

I noticed the following behaviour on multiple days. I first tried it last Thursday (2016-04-28), the most recent try was today (2016-05-02), a few minutes ago.

**What I did:**

- Opened my job search/matching preferences page (https://stackoverflow.com/users/jobsearch/4320236)
- Scrolled down to the section "Match preferences"
- Set my preferences (previously empty):

  - Checked "Always include my current location" (location name shows up in list, with a home icon)
  - Checked "Willing to work remotely"
  - Set levels for seniority
  - Set amount and currency for annual compensation
  - Checked "Full time permanent"
- Scrolled further down and clicked "Save" button

---

**What happened:**

- The page refreshes
- The section "Match preferences" is displayed empty again

---

**What I expected to happen:**

- The page updates (full or partial update via AJAX)
- If there was an error, a message should be shown, indicating what's wrong and ideally a suggestion how to fix it.
- If there was no error, the updated information should be displayed in the UI elements. Additionally a message might be shown (i.e. in case of a partial page update) indicating that the data was updated.

---

*Additional information*

I checked, just to try it, to change the "Job search status" radio box. That setting is being persisted and updated as expected. After having verified that this worked, I set the job search status back and re-tried changing the "Match preferences", but it still did not work.

Comment: we were moving some cheese around right around the time you were trying to modifying your preferences, can you try editing them again please?

Comment: I tried again right now (2016-05-06). It works. Thanks for fixing!

Comment: I've got very similar problem. It looks like "save" button doesn't work.

Comment: I, too, have been having the same problem for the last couple of days.

Comment: @m0sa Always when I push the _Save_ button, I get in debug console message _POST http://stackoverflow.com/users/jobsearch/2369384/submit 404 (Not Found)_

Comment: @RomanPlischke should be working now, this route was previously only allowed for the user story beta participants